# Is it possible to create a folder using CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR drag and drop?

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, explorer

I have a working implementation to drag and drop using `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` and `CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` based on the “What a drag” series from Raymond Chens blog:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/tag/what-a-drag

It works fine for pasting one or more non-existing files to any Explorer window.

The next thing I would like to achieve is to paste a whole tree of files, for example two files and a folder that contains another file.

Is this possible with the `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` clipboard format? If not is there an alternative?

Maybe something with the `TYMED_ISTORAGE` medium format? (The current solution just uses `TYMED_HGLOBAL`.)

Of course I could create a temporary folder somewhere and create my directory tree there. I'd also have to clean up this temporary folder then which feels hacky. (I think that is what 7-Zip does.)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. FILEDESCRIPTOR structure has dwFileAttributes field. Just set it to FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Denis wrote it is possible to create an empty folder by passing FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY to dwFileAttributes (when the FD_ATTRIBUTES is set in dwFlags).

When you don't need empty directories there is an even easier way to get folders. Just include a relative path in the `cFileName` member.

For example if the Filedescriptor contains:

- `foo\bar`
- `foo\baz`

Explorer will create a `foo` folder with two files in it.

This solution has one drawback: The `cFileName` member can only be up to `PATH_MAX - 1` characters long, so this would not work for deeply nested structures or structures with long file names.